# MDCSnackBar not appear on iOS 13

Tags: swift, mdc-components

I am trying to use MDCSnackBar on my app.

It works well on iOS 12 simulator but the snack bar is not appearing on my phone (iOS 13). I also tried to run the app on a 13.4 simulator and the result is the same

This is how I use MDCSnackBar

```
func showSnackBar(messageText: String){
    let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
    message.duration = 1
    message.text = messageText
    MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Just to be clear, I use Swift 5 with XCode 11. And my app has SceneDelegate in it

Comment: This might help someone in future: For me adding "window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)" in to AppDelegate's "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method for iOS 13 and above, created this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below `podfile` to install the `MDCSnackBar` .

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '12.0'

install! 'cocoapods'

target 'podSnack' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar','109.2.0'
end
```

Code to display `MDCSnackBar`

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents.MaterialSnackbar


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func showAlert(){
        let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
        message.duration = 1
        message.text = "The groundhog (Marmota monax) is also known as a woodchuck or whistlepig."
         MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
    }
}
```

[Output in iOS simulator 13.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn16E.png)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I tried your solution; it was work when I try on a different project. But still didn't work on my project. So I decided to rebuild my app (I copy-paste the files) into a new one, and your solution comes to work.